# Loading large number of images from disk efficiently python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to read images from pascal voc 2012 dataset (total size ~2G) using following function

```
def image2np(name_list,read = True, save=True, path="./VOC2012/JPEGImages/"):
    if read and os.path.isfile("images.npy"):
        print("reading images .... ")
        images = np.load("images.npy")

    else:
        images = []
        for name in name_list:
            img = get_image(name)
            if img is not None:
                images.append(img)
        print("total number of images read :{}".format(len(images)))
        images = np.array(images)
        if save and read == False:
            np.save("images.npy",images)

    return images
```

But the problem is it eats all available ram ( 12G ), why this happening and how can i load images more efficiently ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the answer for someone with similar problem, the thing is jpeg images are compressed when stored in disk so if 30000 images of dimension 256x256 are occupying lets say 512mb in disk loading them on ram will use  30000x256x256x3 ~= 6GB

fortunately there is better way to load images which you can find in below article
[efficient image loading](https://hjweide.github.io/efficient-image-loading)